# Modx Redirector plugin limited resource list

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

Redirector plugin created by Shaun McCormick is a little outdated and I noticed that a bug appeared where not all resources showed up.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first went to the repository to commit a fix in but the file annoyingly isn't being tracked. https://github.com/splittingred/Redirector

Fix:

Open: `/core/componenets/redirector/processors/mgr/resources/getlist.class.php`

Then add an initiator method:

```
public function initialize() {
    $this->setDefaultProperties(array(
        'start' => 0,
        'limit' => 0,
        'sort' => $this->defaultSortField,
        'dir' => $this->defaultSortDirection,
        'combo' => false,
        'query' => '',
    ));

    return true;
}
```

And that should be it. All resources will now show up.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you dont know about filtering.

1. all resouces list.

[image]

2. filtering

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I try and type 'Home' to find the home resource page (As an example) I get too many other pages with home in the title. The limit is too low.  http://i.imgur.com/TixF2aq.png

Comment: If you get too many resources, write more words that should be in the title. Or use more specific words. In any case, you do not need all these resources. you need only one.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but one specific example is the homepage where the client wants to link a redirect to the homepage but cannot because if they type 'home' the homepage doesn't show because there are too many resources with 'home' in the title. You cannot be anymore specific because the page itself is just called 'home' as you can see in the screenshot above. It would be useful if we could input the ID of the page but that doesn't work. I need this to be as user-friendly as possible and they are struggling to setup redirects with the limit on the drop down.

Comment: There is only one solution - create a feature request https://github.com/splittingred/Redirector/issues/new

Comment: Haha thanks but it hasn't been touched since 30 May 2011! I will make one anyway though so thank you. I'll keep to my little bit of code for now because the client would be annoyed waiting! ;)